# Adding Currency to array elements

Tags: c#, arrays, currency

I have an array and I need to put the $ sign on the output when i print the array. I have seen the ValueType but it did not work with me on an array. please help me, what to do?

here is my code

```
string[,] Pizza = new string[5, 5]
        {
            {"Name of Pizza \t",   "Small",        "Medium",       "Large",        "XLarge"},
            {"Plain \t \t",           "8.80",       "12.80",    "16.80",    "20.80"},
            {"Hawaian \t",         "10.90",      "15.90",       "20.90",        "25.90"},
            {"Beefy \t \t",           "10.90",      "16.90",        "21.90",        "26.90"},
            {"Vegetarian \t",       "10.90",      "14.90",      "19.90",        "24.90"}
        };

        //print the array
        Console.WriteLine("what type of Pizza do you want?");
        for (int i = 0; i < Pizza.GetLength (0); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int j = 0; j < Pizza.GetLength (1); j++)
                Console.Write(Pizza[i, j]+'\t');
        }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, i'm still a beginner. What I want to get is the Currency sign before each number in the output

Comment: I dislike the use of the string array to store everything. First, you're storing things in a common data structure as if they are the same thing, which they're not: the name of the pizza and a list of prices per size. Second, you're storing the prices as strings, so you've already lost any knowledge of the fact that these values are numbers. The decimal datatype would be most appropriate for storing the prices, and it provides some simple mechanisms to produce a correctly formatted string value. Standard Format Strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it is the assignment requirement from the lecturer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you

```
string[,] Pizza = new string[5, 5]
{
    {"Name of Pizza \t",   "Small",        "Medium",       "Large",        "XLarge"},
    {"Plain \t \t",           "8.80",       "12.80",    "16.80",    "20.80"},
    {"Hawaian \t",         "10.90",      "15.90",       "20.90",        "25.90"},
    {"Beefy \t \t",           "10.90",      "16.90",        "21.90",        "26.90"},
    {"Vegetarian \t",       "10.90",      "14.90",      "19.90",        "24.90"}
};

//print the array
Console.WriteLine("what type of Pizza do you want?");
for (int i = 0; i < Pizza.GetLength (0); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine();

    for (int j = 0; j < Pizza.GetLength (1); j++)

        if(j > 0 && i > 0){
            Console.Write("$" + Pizza[i, j] + '\t');
        }
        else{
            Console.Write(Pizza[i, j] + '\t');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten.

The core idea behind my solution to your problem is that I'm using the decimal datatype to represent the prices, and I'm using the standard "C" format in order to output them with the appropriate currency symbol.

```
enum PizzaSize
{
    Small,
    Medium,
    Large,
    XLarge
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pizzas = new[] {
            new {
                Name = "Plain",
                Prices = new [] {
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.Small, Price = 8.80M },
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.Medium, Price = 12.80M },
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.Large, Price = 16.80M },
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.XLarge, Price = 20.80M },
                }.ToDictionary(item => item.Size, item => item.Price)
            },
            new {
                Name = "Hawaian",
                Prices = new [] {
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.Small, Price = 10.90M },
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.Medium, Price = 15.90M },
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.Large, Price = 20.90M },
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.XLarge, Price = 25.90M },
                }.ToDictionary(item => item.Size, item => item.Price)
            },
            new {
                Name = "Beefy",
                Prices = new [] {
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.Small, Price = 10.90M },
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.Medium, Price = 16.90M },
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.Large, Price = 21.90M },
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.XLarge, Price = 26.90M },
                }.ToDictionary(item => item.Size, item => item.Price)
            },
            new {
                Name = "Vegetarian",
                Prices = new [] {
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.Small, Price = 10.90M },
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.Medium, Price = 14.90M },
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.Large, Price = 19.90M },
                    new { Size = PizzaSize.XLarge, Price = 24.90M },
                }.ToDictionary(item => item.Size, item => item.Price)
            },
        };

        int maxNameWidth = pizzas.Max(item => item.Name.Length);

        const string nameOfPizzaLabel = "Name of Pizza";

        if (maxNameWidth < nameOfPizzaLabel.Length)
        {
            maxNameWidth = nameOfPizzaLabel.Length;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("what type of Pizza do you want?");

        Console.WriteLine("{0} \t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}",
            nameOfPizzaLabel.PadLeft(maxNameWidth),
            PizzaSize.Small,
            PizzaSize.Medium,
            PizzaSize.Large,
            PizzaSize.XLarge);

        foreach (var pizza in pizzas)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:\t{1:C}\t{2:C}\t{3:C}\t{4:C}",
                pizza.Name.PadLeft(maxNameWidth),
                pizza.Prices[PizzaSize.Small],
                pizza.Prices[PizzaSize.Medium],
                pizza.Prices[PizzaSize.Large],
                pizza.Prices[PizzaSize.XLarge]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My apologies for the complex answer; it may be difficult to understand if you are a beginner. For your reference, here is a list of some of the  tools/techniques that are used in this answer: anonymous types, anonymous arrays, and Linq (specifically the ToDictionary and Max functions).